# Verification of implementations of security protocols

Tags: protocols, research

I'm interested in how an implementation of a security protocol can be verified correct and complete.

The AVISPA project (http://www.avispa-project.org/) can be used to verify the protocol. I guess in theory, you could also use the AVISPA modeling language to generate an implementation.

It should be possible to take an implementation and prove that it is a correct and complete implementation of a protocol. Is there any systems currently available to do this? Is there any active research in this area?